# Порядок операций между вызовами lock unlock

Tags: c++, mutex

К примеру есть такой вод код:

```cpp
void obj::foo() {
  ... // some operations
  std::lock_guard lock{mut_};
  ... // some operations and initialization ariables
  lock.unlock();
  ... // other operations
}
```

Как видно критическая секция находится в середине функции и изолирована с помощью мьютекса. Однако, вроде где-то читал, что компилятор может по своему усмотрению тасовать порядок операций если они не зависят друг от друга, так что я хотел уточнить: гарантируется ли что все, что находтся между инициализацией `lock` и вызовом `lock.unlock()` будет защищено мьютексом? Или, быть может, компилятор может решить что какая-то операция между этими вызовами может исполнятся в другом месте, за пределами блокировки?

Comment: Такая перетасовка нарушит правило *as is*, так что она недопустима...

Comment: С++11 и выше уже имеют модель многопоточной машины с общей памятью, так что ничего переставлять в этом месте они не будут.

Comment: тут больше относится не к мьютексам, а к out of order выполнению. А мьютексы вставляют подходящие барьеры памяти. Но если код в другом месте обращаться к этим переменным без этого же мьютекса, то можно получить весь спектр приключений.

Comment: @KoVadim а вот с этого момента поподробнее: вы имеете ввиду обращение к переменным, которые были созданы в защищенной мьютексом секции?

Comment: мьютекс защищает работу с переменными. Создаете их или просто трогаете - не имеет значения. И если в другом потоке обращаются к этим же переменным без этого же мьютекса, то могут быть разные проблемы

Comment: @KoVadim Это понятно, эти переменные локальные, так что сдесь нет проблем с этим

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: Может переставить, если у него получится доказать, что этого никто не заметит.

---

Компилятор вправе менять по своему произволу операции, их порядок, выбрасывать любые операции и вводить новые, только бы конечный результат был бы одинаковым *с точки зрения однопоточного кода*.
Это разрешение известо как *as-if rule*, и позволяет компилятору генерировать более оптимальный код*.

Различные синхронизирующие конструкции — например, мьютексы — ограничивают свободу компилятора**. Заметные снаружи эффекты (например, состояние **разделяемых между потоками** переменных) на границах работы мьютекса (то есть в точке, где находится lock или unlock) должны быть такими же, как если бы никаких оптимизаций не было.

Прочие изменения всё ещё возможны. Например, если переменная локальна и компилятор видит, что она не видна законными методами из других потоков, он всё ещё может делать с ней что угодно, лишь бы результат был одинаковым.

[Пример](https://godbolt.org/z/Mo89rs8ah): в таком коде

```cpp
int i = 1;
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mutex};
    i = 2;
}
std::cout << i;
```

компилятор clang переносит работу со значением 2 в область *после* отпускания мьютекса, а присвоение значения 1 вовсе выбросил вместе с переменной `i`.

```assembler
    ...
    mov     edi, offset mutex
    call    pthread_mutex_lock
    ...
    mov     edi, offset mutex
    call    pthread_mutex_unlock
.LBB0_4:
    mov     edi, offset std::cout
    mov     esi, 2
    pop     rax
    jmp     std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>::operator<<(int) # TAILCALL
```

Мы видим, что мьютекс защищает не переменные, а *разделяемое состояние*.

---

*Ну и процессор имеет право на подобные трюки тоже, это отдельная тема.

**И заставляют его в свою очередь вставлять в код команды, ограничивающие свободу процессора.